# Can I combine 2 tables in MySQL and update a field?

Tags: mysql

Ok so what I need to do here is, take the sum of all the data with a specific name in the first table.

```
SELECT sum(DKP_Change) FROM 'Attendance' WHERE Name='harrian'
```

then in a DIFFERENT table I need to update the Total_DKP with the sum of the previous table

```
SELECT Total_DKP FROM `Characters` WHERE Name='harrian'
```

I tried the following solution and a few others but I'm not getting any working results

```
SELECT Total_DKP FROM `Characters` WHERE Name='harrian'
set Total_DKP = (SELECT sum(DKP_Change) FROM 'Attendance' WHERE Name='harrian')
```

Comment: You should use UPDATE command then :) But do you want to change 2nd tables value from 1st table total? or do you just want to select the data?

Comment: Change the second tables value to the total of the first tables data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change data in a row, use the **[`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)** statement:

```
UPDATE Characters AS c
SET c.Total_DKP = ( SELECT SUM(a.DKP_Change) 
                    FROM Attendance AS a 
                    WHERE a.Name = 'harrian'
                  )
WHERE c.Name = 'harrian' ;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now how would I do this if I need to subtract a number from a third database?

Comment: If this question has been answered, the usual practice in this site is to accept the answer that helped you most (and if you want upvote other helpful answers). And then post a new question describing the different or more complex problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `Characters` 
SET Total_DKP = (SELECT SUM(DKP_Change) FROM `Attendance` WHERE Name='harrian')
```

Comment: There is more then one entry in the second database, I don't want to set all the Total_DKP Values to the same

Answer (score 0):

Try the following please.

```
    update t1 set t1.secondcolumn = 
        (SELECT sum(blah) as blahsum
            FROM t1 b
         where b.name = 'harran'
        )            
    WHERE t1.name = 'harran'
;
```